# How can I make a autocalculate field in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, autocomplete, triggers, calculated-field

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE game (
    idp                   serial NOT NULL,
    start_pl              integer NOT NULL,
    finis_pl              integer NOT NULL,
    points                 integer NOT NULL
    );
```

When I insert or update column `finis_pl`, I want to autocomplete column points. For example when insert number `1` in `finis_pl` column I want to autoinsert value `15` in `points` column.

I made a function using CASE (because I have only 16 possible values for inserting in points) but I can't make it work with a trigger.

Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: "*can't make it work with a trigger*" is not a valid PostgreSQL error message. Why don't you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, a trigger is the only way that I know of to do something like this.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calc()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
value game.points%TYPE;
BEGIN

        IF NEW.finish_pl=1 WHERE game.idp = NEW.idp THEN
       UPDATE game SET points = 15 WHERE idp = NEW.idp;
  END IF;
        RETURN NEW; 
           
        
    END;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  
  CREATE TRIGGER tr_calc
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF finish_pl
  ON game
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE calc();

Comment: i made this function but i don't know how to implement it:

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcul_punt(val integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE result varchar;
BEGIN
  IF val <1 OR val > 15 THEN val:=0;
  END IF;
  SELECT INTO result 
        CASE val
             WHEN  1 THEN 15
             WHEN  2 THEN 14
             WHEN  3 THEN 13
              ............
             WHEN  8 THEN 8
             WHEN  9 THEN 7
             WHEN 10 THEN 6
             WHEN 11 THEN 5
             WHEN 12 THEN 4
             WHEN 13 THEN 3
             WHEN 14 THEN 2
             WHEN 15 THEN 1 END;
  RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

Comment: Please modify the question [by clicking on the edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7404262/edit) to provide new or more specific information about your question.  Don't use comments to elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing redundant data in the database (i.e. both `finish_pl` and `points`), you could just store `finish_pl` and create a *view* that in addition to the columns of `game` would also compute and include the `points` column.